# How to prompt a user to enter data if nothing is entered for the file name?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Input filename: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    while (input.length() == 0){
        System.out.println("Please enter names: ");
        String names = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

How do I make the program end when no more NAMES are entered?

Comment: Are you saying if the program is run with no arguments in main's parameter?

Comment: Try an empty string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: I don't think the comparison _operator_ is the issue here.

Comment: if nothing is entered in input, the program is supposed to ask for names to be entered.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(input.length() == 0){   // use length() method
        System.out.println("Please enter names: ");
        String names = sc.nextLine(); //Same scanner but read names to enter into an array
        }
    }
```

Comment: After the user is done entering names, how do you store the names into an array and stop the while loop?

Comment: The while loop is only when the user types in nothing. Your question did not address storing names and looping multiple names.